# Prevent Android TextViews from reading prices as numbers

Tags: android, android-layout

Occasionally a TextView with dynamic content will show a price. For example, as part of the content it might say $123.00

Sometimes the content may show a phone number or a URL, so I set android:autolink on the TextView. I want those to be turned into links.

The problem is that prices are turned into phone links. Obviously they are not phone numbers--either the brevity of the number or the presence of a currency code should be enough to figure that out.

What can I do so that phone numbers and URLs are autolinked, but so that prices are not autolinked as if they were phone numbers?

EDIT: There can be mixed content in the text. The specific content comes from another party and is unpredictable. A made-up example could be
"See our new store at 123 Main Street. Open 9-5 M-F. Call us at 123-456-7890 for the latest deals. Prices starting at $123.00. Like us on facebook at http://www.facebook.com/whatever."
In that case I would want the URL to link to the website, the phone number to be linked as a phone number, but the price to NOT be linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have the knowledge of what the data type is and as such I would suggest not to use autolink but rather set your own onClickListener that adds the desired action.

Comment: Depending on the creation of the View, your approach would do more harm than good. Pretty easy to fix.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying .. what harm? what fix? .. just enabling and disabling autolink? if so sure.. if you are sure it works the way intended for all the data you have..

Comment: Manfred, can you explain more of how to hotlink certain words in a TextView and have different actions on click for different words?

Comment: Your initial post did not clarify that you have a mixed content in there and just want some of the text to link.. if thats the case I dont know..

Comment: Actually the only hack I know for that would be to user html with the correct links created in it. I have seen that work but not done myself.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to modify the Adapter to use some Regular Expression to figure out your logic and then control the AutoLink Dynamically based on the content being retrieved. This is of course assuming you're using a ListView. If you're not using a ListView, then when the View is being built, control it according to the Regular Expression.

Comment: I don't fully understand, but it sounds like you're suggesting that I programmatically determine whether to turn autolink on or off for the TextView after checking what text is inside. What if, in a paragraph of text, there is a phone number AND a price? I can't just turn autolink on or off completely--I need to make it smarter.

Comment: You should have said that in your initial post, you made it sound like the content is isolated... that is indeed a problem.